# How to correctly perform an AJAX request in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I have made a form in the template with a `{% csrf_token %}`tag, the form output as below:

```
 <form id="appl_detail13" action="/13/devices/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="gTOpBTi6rljV5dKsGE0kuzD1IkghAlzW7GdiBZw6pMMaMUxJSlVev5YqPef6jhjb">
   <input name="appl_checkbox" id="5" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input applcheck" value="13"> 
</form>
```

On checkbox click i perform the ajax request, but i don't send the csrf token:

```
$(".applcheck").click(e=>{
    $.post('/13/devices/',{data:'postedvalue'}, data=> {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

Url Mapper:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /13/devices/
  path('<int:application_id>/devices/', views.ApplicationDetail, name='application-detail'),
]
```

My view accepts the request and should send JSON.

```
def ApplicationDetail(request, application_id):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        device = Device.objects.all().filter(application_id=application_id)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', device)

        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
     else:
        return HttpResponse('no posted')
```

So i get the below error:

[image]

P.S. I know there are a lot of tutorials on this, but many of them are outdated and there are broken links.

Comment: i don't see where you declaring `requestUrl`

Comment: I have added a dummy example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add CSRF in header of ajax calls try this -

```
(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
  });

  function getCookie(c_name)
  {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0)
  {
      c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      if (c_start != -1)
      {
          c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
          c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
          if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
          return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
      }
  }
  return "";
  }
}());
```

Comment: I did please look my input with type hidden, it's the output

Comment: It worked but why this has to be that complicated? I am waiting for other answers as well

Comment: Its not complicated. If your javascript is inside your template, you can use a template variable `{{ csrf_token }}` to set the header. If your javascript is in a separate file the. You can’t use templating language and have to get it from the cookie. The getCookie function is generic and can be useful for many other scripts.

Comment: Alternatively, again if your js is in its own file, you can fetch the value of the hidden input field of your form as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score 0):

If you call from form that it's not exactly how you send an Ajax request( because it load the page)

This is how you send an ajax request with csrf:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/13/devices/",
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{csrf_token}}');
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
```

Well if you want your javascript file to accept Django just declare global variable in javascript(in your template `script` tag `before` you import the javascript with ajax request):

```
<script>
   var csrfToken = {{ csrf_token }};
</script>
```

and in your javascript just use:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrfToken);
},
```

Comment: I don't need `{% csrf_token %` in my form?

Comment: yes, csrf just a random token generate by django cookie or session

Comment: This solution only works if this javascript is part of the html template. It won’t work if you include the script via `src=...`.

Comment: its a matter of passing django variable to javascript which i had put in my edited answer